# Word for "little body"?

Tags: word-formation, diminutives

Is there any term (a diminutive) in English for "little body"? I suppose that the forms such as "bodylet" and "bodyling" are utterly incorrect.

Here is the context: "Graving snow caressing the **little body** dismembered".

Comment: It's better to show signs of at least a little research before asking a question on ELU, Soulmirror. What can you find in AHD, Collins, M-W, Webster's ... concerning your suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide more context? *Little body* of work? *Little body* in a fashion model? *little body* on a car?

Comment: Little body of a person, but in more poetic way to emphasize its fragility. "Little body of hers", for example

Comment: [Corpuscle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corpuscle) is an anglicized version of the diminutive of Latin *corpus,* body, but OED lists the sense "Little body (of an animal)" as *Obs.* Still, its application to, say, red blood cells or erythrocytes is current, and *those* are tiny bodies of a sort. If you mean a tiny human, there is *[homunculus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homunculus),* but that term does not exclude the animating psyche.

Answer (score 2):

While not a noun, the adjective **[petite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/petite)** is often used to mean

> (Of a woman) having a small and attractively dainty build:
>   *she was petite and vivacious* [ODO]

Note that is is almost always applied to women or girls, and is generally positive in tone.

The term **[bantam](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bantam)** means

> a small but aggressive person [Collins English Dictionary]

This generally refers to the entire person, including his attitude, not just his body.

Similarly, **[Lilliputian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Lilliputian)** (with or without capitalization) means

> A trivial or very small person or thing. [ODO]

Again, there is a tonal connotation, in this case suggesting *unimportant*.

The term **midget** has a long and checkered history. Currently it is usually characterized as objectionable. The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/midget) labels its definition as *offensive*

> An extremely or unusually small person.

A further discussion of the term and its pejorative nature can be found in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midget).

Comment: Great suggestions. But it's utterly unclear what's being asked.  Is it a word for **"a small person"** like Napoleon (eg ......... "short", say) or is it a word you would use, say, in an abattoir to describe smaller hangs ... or what? MiniMe -like comic figures??

Answer (score 0):

How about "corpuscle?"

(from Merriam-Webster Online:)

Main Entry: cor·pus·cle 
Pronunciation: \ˈkȯr-(ˌ)pə-səl\
Function: noun
Etymology: Latin corpusculum, diminutive of corpus

Comment: Whatever its use in Latin, *corpuscle*'s meanings in modern English do not include *little body*, and using the word in this way would only introduce confusion.

Comment: @choster \\ (Excuse the delay: I did not realize that you had commented.) I disagree with what you apparently are contending -- i.e., that a loss of meaning (that a word might undergo as a language evolves) cannot under any circumstance be restored.

Comment: I do not deny that a word may regain a lost meaning, but I do contend that using an obsolete and obscure sense of a word is more likely to inhibit communication than enrich it, unless one is a celebrity, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try ectomorphic - which describes the physical body structure:

> ec·to·mor·phic /ˌɛktəˈmɔrfɪk/ [ek-tuh-mawr-fik] [source][1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ectomorphic)
>
> adjective
>
> Having a thin body build, roughly characterized by the
>   relative prominence of structures developed from the embryonic
>   ectoderm (contrasted with endomorphic, mesomorphic ).
>
> Origin: 1935–40;
>   ecto- + -morphic